# Show that $e^z = e^{z+2\pi i}, \,\, \forall z.$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Show that $e^z = e^{z+2\pi i}, \,\, \forall z.$

I know that $e^{2\pi i}$ is periodic function with period $2\pi i$ but I still can not find the solution of this..

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: $e^{2\pi i} $ is not a periodic function, it is just the number 1.

Comment: I can't believe no one has brought this up yet, but what, exactly, are you allowed to assume with regard to complex exponentiation?

Comment: What property of the (complex) exponential are you allowed to use ? [Other than the well-known fact it has the period $i2\pi$.]

Answer (score 1):

Remember of Euler Formula:
$$
e^{i y} = \cos y + i \sin y
$$
Note that $e^{i 2 \pi} = \cos 2 \pi + i \sin 2 \pi = 1$. It's follows from exponentiation property:
$$
e^{z + 2  \pi i} = e^z e^{2 \pi i} = e^z 1 = e^z
$$

Answer (score 1):

By Euler’s formula we have that $$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $\sin$ and $\cos$ are $2\pi$-periodic functions on $\mathbb{R}$ then $$e^{i(2k\pi +x)}= \cos(x+2k\pi)+i\sin(x+2k\pi)= \cos(x)+i\sin(x)=e^{ix}.$$ This proves that the function $x \mapsto e^{ix}$ is also $2\pi$-periodic on all the real line.

Finally, let $z=a+bi \in \mathbb{R}$, so $$e^z=e^{a+bi}=e^ae^{bi},$$ and since $e^{ib}$ is $2\pi-periodic$ then the result follows.

Comment: Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers, posted years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $e^{2\pi i}=1$, not a periodic function. Use the laws of indices: $$e^{z+2\pi i}=e^ze^{2\pi i}=e^z.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $e^{2\pi i} = 1$. Thus, $e^{z+2\pi i} = e^z e^{2\pi i} = e^z$.